# Когда есть смысл создавать отдельную таблицу для данных в БД

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-7

Есть такая модель:

```cs
public class SubDomain
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Имеет 100 вариантов 1-100
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
    // Точность до дня, имеет около 1к вариантов
    public DateTime LoadData { get; set; }
    //имеет 14 вариантов расширения типа ".exe"
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    //имеет 5к вариантов.
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

В модели есть еще поля, но я их убрал, чтобы было короче.

У меня более 6кк записей, и данные в этих записях по-любому будут повторятся. Есть ли смысл такие повторяющиеся данные выводить в отдельную таблицу?

Например, вынести дату загрузки в отдельную таблицу, в этой таблице будет 1к дат и потом уже в главной таблице давать на нее ссылку.

```cs
public class DataLoad
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoadData { get; set; }
}
```

В размере БД я вроде как выиграю при таком подходе, а в скорости работы?

Есть какие-нибудь пороговые значения, при которых на данные нужно заводить отдельную таблицу?

Comment: звучит как вопрос про нормализацию/денормализацию БД и когда что использовать, погуглите может поможет

Comment: В размере ты точно проиграешь. Что ссылка что дата это просто число, но с отдельной таблицей у тебя будет ещё 2000 чисел и таблица. И лишние join-ы при попытке выбрать что-нибудь по дате. В общем неудачный выбор.

Comment: *"В размере БД я вроде как выиграю"* - только если бд сама не использует сжатие.

Comment: Гораздо логичнее вынести в отдельную таблицу автора. Обычно их сильно меньше чем записей и они более сложной структуры. Например завтра вы решите что автору нужно хранить фио и дать возможность менять логин. Отдельную таблицу вы просто расширите дополнительной колонкой и поменяете одно поле, а ссылка по id у миллиона файлов никак не поменяется.

Comment: `Когда есть смысл создавать отдельную таблицу` - тогда, когда у вас есть **отдельная** сущность, пригодная для масштабирования. Всякие ID, время, и прочее - это детали одной конкретной сущности. Или вы будете еще и имена с фамилиями в отдельную таблицу запихивать? Ну согласитесь, не очень удобно, да и как-то бредово потом это будет выглядеть... Вот "Автор" - это да, у вас должна быть отдельная таблица, а не просто строковое значение.

Comment: 3 НФ вроде отвечает на все эти вопросы.

Comment: У вас таки дата или дата и время? Если только дата, то в некоторых БД можно использовать для этого отдельный тип именно дата, он будет занимать меньше места, чем дата-время. И нет смысла выносить дату в отдельную таблицу, кроме неудобства это ничего не принесёт.

Comment: Кхм... [Calendar date dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(data_warehouse)#Calendar_date_dimension) - иногда даже даты выносят в отдельную таблицу. Когда я впервые с таким столкнулся, долго думал...

Comment: Рассмотрим, например, `FileType`. Допустим, мы хотим показать все имеющиеся варианты пользователю. Если они в отдельной таблице, то сделать это легко и быстро. Если они в таблице `SubDomain`, то придётся выбирать distinct из 6 млн строк. Впрочем, это смягчается наличием индексов.

Comment: Выборка или поиск по Id автора будет быстрее, чем по строке, так что в любом случае авторов выгодно поместить в отдельную таблицу (индексы какие-то операции ускоряют, а какие-то замедляют). А вообще, факторов, которые нужно учитывать, довольно много. Например, есть ли связи с другими таблицами; преобладающие операции (в основном, будут ли записи изменяться).